# Converting a GeoJSON file to vector tiles compatible with CesiumJS in Java

Tags: java, vector-tiles, cesium, xyz-tiles

When I explored on google, I found a lot of packages in Github which were in JavaScript or NodeJS. Did anyone has written a code or came across a library in Java to convert GeoJSON to tiles?

Answer (score 0):

Java Mapbox Vector Tile Library for Encoding/Decoding

https://github.com/wdtinc/mapbox-vector-tile-java